# Entity Framework doesn't update bit datatype

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have added a new column `IsForceLogOff` (datatype = Bit). When I update the table in the usual way, everything updates except the newly added bool column.

```
public static UserErrorStatus UserUpdate(User user, Company company)
{
    UserErrorStatus status = UserErrorStatus.Error;

    using (OAPDataLayerEntities DbEntity = GetDBContext())
    {
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                user.IsForceLogOff = true;
                DbEntity.Users.Attach(user);
                DbEntity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);

                DbEntity.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Complete();

                DbEntity.AcceptAllChanges();
                status = UserErrorStatus.Success;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AddressID] [int] NULL,
    [AccountTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StaffID] [int] NULL,
    [SalutationID] [int] NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SecurityQuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SecurityAnswer] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CompanyID] [int] NULL,
    [DateCreated] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateModified] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateLastLogin] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserIDModified] [int] NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [ntext] NULL,
    [IsForceLogOff] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

Refer to the above sql

Comment: Show us the CREATE TABLE table definition, user entity and the onconfiguring for a user

Comment: @CaiusJard Updated the question with screenshot of entity details

Comment: I was more hoping for a right click table>>script as>>create>>to clipboard, and then paste text.. also, I asked for 3 things and you provided 1

Comment: @CaiusJard  I have updated the question. Please note that there is an issue with how I am updating the table and not in the table structure. Appreciate your answer on the C# code that I have written to update

Comment: Yes.. Providing the table create allows us to a) see if something like a default could be giving trouble and b) exactly replicate your table so we can easily make one in our machine and try to reproduce/fix your issue

Comment: There are still two missing items I asked for: *Show us the CREATE TABLE table definition **(1, provided)**, user entity **(2, missing)** and the onconfiguring for a user **(3, missing)***

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s Noted, Appreciate if you could provide an answer for the update issue

Answer (score 1):

The typical suspect is that at runtime the application is using a different database instance than the one you are checking. With a breakpoint verify the connection string used /w `var conn = DbEntity.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` (EF6) or `DbEntity.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString` for pre-EFCore 5, or `DbEntity.Database.ConnectionString` for EF Core 5. (thank you Microsoft...)

In your example, the use of the TransactionScope is completely unnecessary, and in cases where a TransactionScope would be practical, you have them the wrong way around. TransactionScope should be the outer-most boundary, with the `using (var DbEntity = ...` being declared inside the scope.

TransactionScopes add an additional cost to processing and would be used to coordinate transactions between the DbContext operations and other *external* operations, such as operations with other DbContexts or other services etc. that comply with transaction commit/rollback strategies. DbContexts inherently operate with a Transaction internally so it doesn't matter how many entities you update within the scope of a DbContext and it's `SaveChanges` call, they will be saved within a single transaction.